# How to add more audio channels to playback device?

Tags: windows-10, audio, gaming, speakers

I have an Asus ROG Strix gaming laptop. Windows 10 OS version 1803 and my problem is that in some games that I play the audio works and in some it doesn't. I was able to cross check and identify that this had something to do with the audio channels a playback device can support.

Let me explain this in detail. My default speakers, the in-built speakers of my laptop don't play audio for some games like Dying Light, FIFA 19, Shadow of War etc. However when I connect my bluetooth earphones, headphones, speakers or connect to my Android TV using HDMI my game audio works fine through them.

So when I checked the audio channels the bluetooth devices were providing they all were set to 1 channel 16 bit 8KHz-24KHz Telephone quality or CD quality. But my default laptop speakers or my wired JBL Headsets showed me 24Bit/16 Bit 48Khz options only. I asked my friends with Windows 10 and 8 and literally every one of them had around 8-9 options in their audio channels for their in built speakers with all sorts of combinations in the channel options.

Initially since my bluetooth devices worked, I kind of ignored this problem but today when I installed Tomb Raider , none of the playback devices I had functioned properly. Now I don't know how to explain this issue to the game support guys, so I thought I will first try to solve my original issue.

Please help me understand what the root cause of my issue is and if I can increase the number of channels in my audio device(which I suppose you can't right?).

Thank you.

I use an Nvidia GTX 1050ti 4 GB graphic card, if this helps.

[My default device's audio channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxx2B.png)

Comment: It sounds like you have audio driver issues. Have you checked for updated audio drivers? Basically, you're already doing something almost no one else has to do. Your speakers aren't a problem. When you connect the Bluetooth devices it's probably bypassing your audio system entirely. So you need to go back to that point and resolve the root problem.